# Trying to download and setup the certificate from a remote SSL address for WebSocket connection but getting a "Signature does not match" exception

Tags: java, ssl, https, websocket, ssl-certificate

First I downloaded the certificate with:

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -connect io.lightstream.bitflyer.com:443 -showcerts 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -out bitflyer.cer
```

Then I imported the certificate into a keychain:

```
keytool -import -file bitflyer.cer -alias bitflyer -keystore bitflyer.jks -storepass "abc123" -keypass "abc123"
```

So I'm trying to connect to `io.lightstream.bitflyer.com:443`. Below my full handshake:

```
Sending HTTP handshake! req=GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: io.lightstream.bitflyer.com
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 0enPg4mnHvLcT6s7+4mEGA==
Origin: http://www.websocket.org
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

But then I get:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed
    at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:215)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:289)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1626)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:449)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:392)
    at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:213)
    ... 21 more
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong or how to debug that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> openssl s_client -connect io.lightstream.bitflyer.com:443
> ```

The certificates you get here depend on the OpenSSL version. Up to 1.0.2 the `server_name` extension (SNI) was not automatically used (i.e. you had to explicitly to use `-servername`) and without the the resulting certificate is a self-signed certificate for "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate". With SNI though the certificate is the proper certificate for "io.lightstream.bitflyer.com".

My guess is that you actually added to the certificate for "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate" while Java is using SNI and thus getting the certificate for "io.lightstream.bitflyer.com" instead. Or it might be the other way around, depending on your version of OpenSSL, of Java and of the actual Java code.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm on Mac and my openssl version is `LibreSSL 2.8.3`. I did what you suggested, adding `-servername io.lightstream.bitflyer.com` but now I just get a `No trusted certificate found` :(